# Virtual layer accessing virtual field

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer, virtual-field

I have a layer `my_layer` containing a virtual field `virtual_1`. Next step I want to create a virtual layer, which list only unique values (as a bonus also dissolves the geometries by unique values).

The following query for the virtual layer doesn't work with virtual fields:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT virtual_1 from my_layer
```

How could the desired outcome be achieved?

Some notes/ideas:

- I need an dynamic solution, as the data in `my_layer` gets updated reguarly. So unfortunately the Vector>Analysis>Unique Values isn't an option. Also Dissolving by virtual field is therefore not an option.
- Would it work to generate the virtual field inside the query itself? How could an expression of the field editor evaluated in the  virtual-field-query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created a virtual field (Virtual_1) using a CASE statement you may use the case statement in your SQL query

In the below exemple I create a virtual field (Virtual_1) using the following :

```
CASE
    WHEN "continent" IN ( 'North America' , 'South America' )
        THEN 'On the Left'
    WHEN "continent" IN ( 'Africa' , 'Asia' , 'Europe' )
        THEN 'On the Right'
    WHEN "continent" =  'Antarctica' 
        THEN 'A the Bottom'
    ELSE 'Other'
END
```

To use this Virtual field in a Virtual layer I could just use the following SQL statement where the virtual field is replaced by the CASE expression:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT (CASE
            WHEN "continent" IN ( 'North America' , 'South America' )
                THEN 'On the Left'
            WHEN "continent" IN ( 'Africa' , 'Asia' , 'Europe' )
                THEN 'On the Right'
            WHEN "continent" =  'Antarctica' 
                THEN 'A the Bottom'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END) AS Virtual_1 
FROM Admin_0_polygons
```

In the below picture you can see the original table with the virtual field and the Virtual layer next to it.

[image]

The same principle will work with any fonction that SQLite/SpatiaLite engine could evaluate including on the geometry if needed

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This helped a lot. Is it correct that not all QGIS expression functions work? e.g. concatenate(), or if()?

Comment: Also I realized, that i cannot use fields defined in the SQL query within subsequent field definitions of the SQL query? Is there a way around this?

Comment: For your first question IIF() and concat() will work (in fact you can use any expression from sqlite not from QGIS expression engine). For your second question it's unclear what you mean but I'm able to use the Virtual_1 field created in the query in ORDER BY or GROUP BY in the same query

Comment: Regarding first question: OK. I understand. Concatenate (!=concat) does not work (only QGIS expression, not sqlite)
Regarding second: I try to achieve the following in the same SQL request: "SELECT *somedefinition* as virtual_1, Group_Concat(virtual_1) as virtual_2 FROM Admin_0_polygons Group by some_other_field" How would I achieve it?